# iphone ipad nib return same self.view.frame.size.width issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to get the current dimension of the screen.
i used self.view.frame.size.width

`NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.width)`

so when I run in the iphone simulator , it will return 320
however, when i run in the ipad simulator, it will still return me 320

I have different nib files for iphone and ipad
and they're getting the proper nib files and the target family is ipad/iphone
it should return 768 and so i can resize the images according to that.

any ideas?

Comment: To get screen dimension you can use this: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/width. I don't post it as an answer since I don't answer your question about the same value on iPhone and iPad. Still, I hope it will help :)

Comment: In which method did you place the NSLog?

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. Gives the impression that they are returning different values which would make sense. Can you please change your title to be more accurate.

Comment: Do you use ~ipad postfix of the NIB filename for iPad?

Comment: just to clarify, have you changed the Devices to Universal in Targets->Summary page in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

try and use these

```
CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat screenheight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
```

but UIScreen doesn't take into account the current interface orientation.
you will have to check for that also

or directly check for the device type

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

and

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your targeted devices to Universal as in this picture

[image]

Comment: @Kiddo have you double checked that you are presenting the nib for iPad when running on the iPad?

Comment: @Kiddo Where do you have the NSLog?

Answer (score 0):

Is your iPad Nib file being used when running in a iPad Simulator? Maybe you want to check by changing something (maybe, change the location of,say, a button) in the iPad's NIB. This way, when the App runs, you can check if it's the iPhone's NIB or iPad's Nib.

Answer (score 0):

First you check this:-

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
and

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

And also while allocating file:-

For iPhone:-
ABController *controller = [[ABController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABController~iPhone" bundle:nil];

For iPad:-
ABController *controller = [[ABController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABController~iPad" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

```
 self.view.autoresizesSubviews=NO;
 Imageview.autoresizingMask=NO;
```

is set to NO.

That will do your work